# How to pass flexible amount of arguments using getopt in Python?

Tags: python, getopt

I'm new to Python and what I have learnt from getopt is that I can pass command line arguments while executing the python script. Now my question is, is there a way to not set the number of arguments that I can pass in the command line?

My code looks something like this:

```
try:
     opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"h:1:2:3:4:",["help=", "1week=","2week=", "3week=", "4week="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
     print 'test.py -1 <week 1> -2 <week 2> -3 <week 3> -4 <week 4>'
     sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
     if opt == '-h':
          print 'test.py -1 <week 1> -2 <week 2> -3 <week 3> -4 <week 4>'
          sys.exit()
     elif opt in ("-1", "--1week"):
          week1 = arg
     elif opt in ("-2", "--2week"):
          week2 = arg
     elif opt in ("-3", "--3week"):
          week3 = arg
     elif opt in ("-4", "--4week"):
          week4 = arg
```

And to run the above code I use
`python test.py -1 89 -2 88 -3 87 -4 86`. Is there anyway I can modify this where in I don't have to always give 4 arguments, but also 3? I want it to be flexible where in sometimes I might give 3 arguments or 4.

Comment: Unless you are using an old version of python you should use argparse instead of getopt

Comment: There's no way to do this using getopt is it? I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Alright. I'm looking into argparse

Comment: @Matt: getopt is not deprecated. It is for people who want or familiar with [getopt() C function interface](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt). Otherwise argparse is recommended.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian oh, right. I was thinking about optparse

Comment: btw, your program works as is e.g., if you omit `-3` option then `week3` keeps its default value. You should probably use a list instead of `var1, var2, var3, ...` individual variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getopt() not enforcing required arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045821/getopt-not-enforcing-required-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program accepts one or more week numbers:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('weeks', nargs='+', type=int, help='weeks numbers')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

#### Example

```
$ python your_script.py 1 2 3
```

#### Output

```
Namespace(weeks=[1, 2, 3])
```

To produce `'weekly_1_2_3'` from the above `args.weeks`:

```
result = 'weekly_' + '_'.join(map(str, args.weeks))
```

The result is `'weekly_1_2_3_4'` for `1 2 3 4` command line.

Comment: Ok, can I store the '1' '2' '3' into a variable while I'm passing it in the command line? Because these values will be used somewhere down the line in the rest of the script.

Comment: @user1452759: `args.weeks` is a list of integers (notice: `type=int` above)

Comment: I don't want them in a list. I want them stored in separate variables.

Comment: @user1452759: what do you want to happen if `week4` is not defined?

Comment: The values that I'll be passing as arguments into the command line will be used to create a directory, say, 'weekly_1_2_3_4. If week4 is not defined, it should create a directory 'weekly_1_2_3.

Comment: @user1452759: I've updated the answer to include the example how to create `weekly_1_2_3_4` from `args.weeks`.

Comment: Sebastian - THANK YOU SO MUCH for the help!! This works!! I see that using it this way was a better idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `argparse` (python 2.7) instead.  By default all options are considered optional. `argparse` includes a `required` attribute for "required options".

For example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--firstname', dest='fn', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--greeting', dest='grt', nargs='?', choices=['hello', 'goodbye'], default='hello')
parser.add_argument('--repeat', dest='rpt', nargs='?', default=1, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

for n in range(args.rpt):
    print "%d: %s, %s" % (n+1, args.grt, args.fn)
```

Comment: Can you please provide me with a simple example as to how to do this. I'm looking at some documentations here and they are VERY confusing!

Comment: Sure - give me a few minutes and I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: why do you think `getopt` doesn't support optional arguments? Try the code from the question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, you're correct.  I was thinking about the `required` keyword available in `argparse`, which enables more explicit control over optional vs. required arguments, but didn't express myself very clearly.  Answer updated.

Comment: "required option" is an oxymoron. It shouldn't be used unless it is absolutely necessary e.g., to support legacy command-line interface.

Comment: @David - Thank you for providing me with this example.